# Button action is not moving to another vc in which sidebar is emmended

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

[image]
[image]

When I click on the button, the screen is not changed in which sidebar is embedded. I think it is a problem related to the class name given `SWRevealView` Controller to 2nd controller.

Can any one help me to sort out this problem? My code is:

```
- (IBAction)check:(id)sender {

    SWRevealViewController *vc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dash"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Do you check the identifier? Is vc is nil here?

Comment: yes it is not nil..when i click on login button then dasboard screen in which side bar is embeded with the help of SWRevealviewController is not open..the stimulator just open and close

Comment: Do you have navigation controller here?

Comment: I given class name to dashboard screen is SWRevealviewcontroller and give identifier "dash" and use logic this:                     SWRevealViewController *vc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dash"]; [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: can you show your storyboard scene

Comment: No my question from where you are tapping the button? Is that viewcontroller is under navigation controller?

Comment: where you want to open the side menu from login or somewhere else

Comment: no srry..i did not use navigation controller

Comment: i am tapping the button from login screen.in login screen on login button is there when i press on that it does not move to dashboard screen in just only sidebar is embedded..but when side is not there it moved to dasboard screen

Comment: And i given dashboard screen class name SWRevealViewController and after on login button action code is used.                           SWRevealViewController *vc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dash"]; [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I tried sample one for your question.It shows the reveal view controller using button action.

First set the View Controller.Then set the Reveal View Controller.

```
 Utilities->Click Identity Inspector->Go to Identity(It is below to Custom Class)->Give 'dash' in Storyboard ID
```

First Screenshots show the ViewController and Reveal View Controller

[image]

Then I set 'dash' in storyboard id

[image]

Now in ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)check:(id)sender
{
  SWRevealViewController *vc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dash"];
  [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: this is the case of push..but i am using modal logic to move to another screen..in this navigation controller is no need

Comment: First of all please tell me can we give name class to SWRevealVIewController??

Comment: class name means name of Storyboard??

Comment: can any one help me Plz??

Comment: No don't give class name to SWRevealViewController

Comment: Wait I help you now

Comment: Then how i adjust sidebar without this class name

Comment: How do you set the SWRevealViewController to loginViewController?

Comment: one view controller is there in which login button is there and another is SWRevealViewController in which side bar is there..so move from one view controller to SwRevealViewController i used login on button action in which code is                                                                                           - (IBAction)check:(id)sender {

    SWRevealViewController *vc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dash"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}

Comment: it is not moving to next screen it just show black screen after button tapping

Comment: simply think you just make side bar first then you take another Storyboard in which one button is there,by tapping that button you just have to move on  side bar  screen how you will do that??

Comment: I gave you answer what you ask in your question

Comment: can u tell me again i didn't understand??

Comment: Without UINavigationController you can't do

Comment: how it is possible??

Comment: @Bansal - if you are answered my questiion it is easy to resolve 1. where **you want to open the side menu from login or somewhere else** 2. **can you show your storyboard scene**

Comment: Brother give me a chance to answer.By your help I learned this.If my answer is not clear post your answer.

Comment: it is still not done with pushviewcontroller...yaa afcorse.@user3182143                   and @anbu.Karthik---  second screen side bar and first screen button by which move to second screen

Comment: @Bansal - some where means inside the SWL (is ROOT )or outside the SWL (is not a root)

Comment: Bansal I help you.Can you show your storyboard scene?

Comment: Are you there Bansal?

Comment: Now did you get the solution?

Comment: @user3182143 are you here??

Comment: i just want to know just how to add view controller before SWRevealviewcontroller

Comment: See my above screenshot where I added the ViewController before RevealViewController.

Comment: yaw,ok it"s done but it little bit some another way..and thanks for help me and giving an idea.